# unit testing in an entangled spring context

Tags: spring, junit, mockito, springmockito

Given a legacy application has 1500 spring.xmls. I want to write a unit test for a service. I am deep in the dependency hell. I have to accept the app as is, no way out.

So we use spring-3.something and mockito-1.9 and I want the nice way to test a service. Newer code heavily use @Autowired annotation.

Indirectly, the service uses ~25 helpers (factory methods etc.) which I actually want to use in the test, and ~25 objects which I am not interested in for this test.

I currently try to setup the context in the way outlined above, but I am confused about the effects of @Mock, @InjectMocks, @Autowired.

My test is given below. I need assistance to set it up correctly.

**Questions:**

- **what is the actual effect of @InjectMocks ?**
- **how can I decide (technically) which autowired beans are really used, and which are replaced by mocks?**
- **I know, am misusing mocks to get fakes. Is there an easier way to get fakes in one-liners?**
- **Please note that I want to understand this as I have loads of such services... **

Here's my sample:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "classpath:/some/path/MainTestConfig.spring.xml"
})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class SampleTest {

    // ***            Uninteresting Dependencies to be mocked        *** //
    @Mock Mock1 mock1;
    @Mock Mock2 mock2;

    /** Service under test */
    @Autowired
    SomeService service;

    // ***            Tightly coupled helpers to be used              *** //
    @Autowired Helper1 helper1
    @Autowired Helper2 helpr2

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(SampleTest.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSample() {

        // prepare dummy context
        SomeContext context = new Context();

        // define expected result
        int expectedValue = 42;

        //execute method under test, record result
        Result actualResult = service.execute(context);

        //make assertions on result
        assertTrue(actualResult.getSomething()==expectedValue);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't get why you would have the `mock1` and `mock2` that doesn't seem to be relevant in your test as they are irrelevant. Plus the helpers don't seem to be used, verified in the test. If everything is wired by spring why would you want it. I believe you should actually mock the tightly coupled helpers instead, and verify the interactions. Also eventually you could write this test as a big functionality / feature test i.e. not a unit test nor an integration test, hence it will be placed in some other package to show the difference your colleagues.

Comment: By the way did you tried the annotation config available in spring 3 ? It might be useful if you need to inject only a few dependencies, and that could work for mocks too (no need for springockito, if adding another maven dependency is a concern).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wanted to post this as a separate answer since this should better address your actual question regarding @Mock, @Autowired and @InjectMocks.

`@Mock`: This marks a field that should be created as a mock (using `mock(MyClass.class)`) when `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` is called.

`@Autowired`: Marks a field that should be assigned by Spring with a bean that implements the class / interface.

`@InjectMocks`: Marks a field that should be CREATED by Mockito when `MockitoAnnoations.initMocks(this)` is called. It creates an instance of the class and injects the `@Mock`-annotated fields into this instance. (see correction to this statement in comments).

Analysis:

`@InjectMocks` is not compatible with Spring contexts and `@Autowired` because `InjectMock` creates a new instance of the class it does not use the Spring instance.

To do what you are looking for, you need to use [Springockito](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home). (delayed update) Springockito will allow you to inject mocks into your Spring context and thereby have those mocks used as `Autowired` candidates. It allows for Mocks and Spys. Using `ReplaceWithMock` and `Autowired` on the same field in your test is the general practice (as is shown in the example on the wiki).

Comment: **This statement is incorrect** : "...`InjectMock` creates a new instance of the class it does not use the Spring instance". The actual Mockito behavior is that it will never create an instance if the field already have one at the time of the mockito injection. Though I admit the documentation isn't clear about that : [`InjectMocks` Javadoc](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html). So it's possible to inject mocks in a spring managed bean, **BUT** I wouldn't recommend it as it adds a lot of complexity in the test setup.

Comment: @Brice so are you saying that if you put `@Autowired` and `@InjectMocks` (Autowired being needed to get the Spring bean) on the same field in a test, the Spring bean will be used and it will be updated by injecting into it the mocks from the test?

Comment: However note the spring managed bean will be updated with the mocks for his whole life in the spring context, so I don't recommend it. Using the dirties context trick can work, but it's way more slow especially with huge spring contexts, as Spring will load the context for each test method.

Answer (score 2):

First question, do you NEED to load the spring context do this test? Generally when I have Spring projects, I have one UNIT test per class that DOES NOT load a context file. I will have a different CONTEXT test for loading the context file and verifying that it loads properly. If you are doing true unit testing I would suggest not loading the context. If the class under test using `@Autowired` to assign dependencies (and so has no setters) use Spring's `ReflectionTestUtils` to assign those fields.

Comment: well, the unit I am testing is the service + its helpers. To do so I need to setup *some* context constisting of the helpers and dummies that do nothing. Setting up this context manually is not feasible for 50 classes so I'd like to reuse existing spring config where possible, and inject mocks where feasible. It seems I do not get the "InjectMocks" yet ...

Comment: BTW: what is "true" unit testing? what is a unit in your opinion? I have doubts replacing unit by "class" or "method". My unit is the service + helpers. Everything beyond that border is to be mocked/faked.

Comment: A "true" unit test is where your test only touches ONE class (the unit). All other classes / dependencies are mocked. The only concrete classes I allow other than the class under test are Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) that just are data holders (fields, getters, setters).

Comment: If you are testing "service + its helpers", I would not consider this a true unit test. Not to say this is a bad test, just differently named. On our project we call this a "feature test" (totally arbitrary name but is distinguished from "unit test"). These are generally more challenging to set up and sometimes do use a limited Spring context. However, they should have fewer tests and not have all the "unit" tests for each class. The purpose of these tests should be to ensure the classes are interacting properly.

Comment: hmm, seems my education on testing used outdated naming: In **The Art of Software 
Testing**, Myers, **1979!** definition is: *Module testing (or unit testing) is a
process of testing the individual subprograms, subroutines, or procedures in a
program.* This is my understanding, but it seems to be in conflict with current (OO-based) understanding of (j)unit testing. Indeed I am looking for an approach to test on bigger level (feature, but not yet completely integrated application) instead of all-too-finegrained tests on class or method level (as I said I live in a legacy context ....)

Comment: And just to be clear, there is nothing wrong with using JUnit to create these higher level tests. It just helps in communication to call them something other than unit tests. WRT your question, you are in a tough spot since you can't isolate the classes into separate spring files. However, could you load just the spring files that are needed rather than the root file that loads the entire application?

Comment: I wouldn't define a "true unit" as always being a single class. Suppose you starts implementing a feature in a single class, but at some point it gets too large or complex. You then starts extracting helper classes from it, making them *package private* as they are merely *implementation detail*. Should these new classes be regarded as separate units, with their own unit tests? I don't think so. I would rather continue to consider the logical unit the same as before, even if now it comprises multiple classes.

Comment: The point I was making is that would suggest that when most people hear "unit test" then interpret this to be a test of a single class with all dependencies mocked. We use JUnit to test these "features" as well but we call them "feature tests". Semantics, I know.